# Add a [contact] magic link to the Contact Us form

Tags: feature-request, magic-links, contact

Sometimes, a user has created multiple accounts by accident. In these cases, I often post a comment starting with something like

> Please use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form to have your accounts merged.

with the aim of helping users editing their question or reply to comments.

Can we have a magic link `[contact]` which auto-expands into this, just like e.g. `[tour]` and `[ask]`?

Comment: Until / unless this is implemented, you can save yourself some typing by using relative links: `[Contact Us](/contact)`